# 2D plane characterization for Euclidian space of >1 dimension

Tags: definition, euclidean-geometry, foundations, plane-geometry

Does the following characterization of a 2D plane hold for all Euclidian spaces of >1 dimension?

Plane: a two-dimensional continuum of points with unbounded area defined by two intersecting lines such that all of the lines it contains which are parallel to one of its defining lines intersect the other defining line

Comment: How are you defining 'parallel' in higher dimensions than 2?

Comment: I like equidistance and non-intersection; a nonzero distance from a point P on line m to the nearest point on line l is independent of the location of P on line m